# Best way to train for a 200m race

Tags: running

I have just won my school's 200m race, which means I qualify for the Athletics in a month's time.

At the moment, my time for 200m is 36.37 secs. I am 12 years old and this is my first race over 200. What should I do to practice for it?

Comment: I meant to add, congratulations for winning. You're doing really well to be motivated, and even better since you are a 12 year old. Good on you. Wish I was that motivated at your age!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my own experience and what I've read:

- Start with warm ups to losen all your muscles, especially lower legs, thighs etc. (anything that will get a workout while you're running)
- Practice your running technique - pumping your arms and stretching your legs
- Develop a strategy for running the race; start strong, keep a good pace through the middle, push yourself to get a little faster, and then try and stop thinking about the race so you can keep pushing your body without getting too tired.

I've found a couple of interesting posts that might help - this one on [strategy for running the race](http://www.athletesacceleration.com/200metertraining.html) and this one on [how to run the race and improve your times](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100409193350AA6wglZ).

Hope this helps, and wish you all the best for your race.

Comment: Perhaps we should add some more specific training exercises, like interval training or practicing sprints?

Answer (score -3):

Train every week. AM 13YEARS old and i used to run 26s in the 200m but after after  3 week of training i ran 24.14 am still 13 though. I ALSO made it to junior champions ship. All i can say is never give up. When you train and your legs are dying just do one more sprint thats when you improve. At the start of the race run about 85 to 90% of speed when you get to the turn run full speed cause your body can run a faster 150m race. Keep your head down the first 20m and ac accelerate.
Good luck. May god be with ya